# finding root of 3rd degree math equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to solve the following equation and give a simple formula for $y$ such that with the known value of $x$ we can easily compute value of $y$. 
$$x = \frac{(c+ky)y^{2}}{2}$$
$c$ and $k$ are constants.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots